# Print 4x4x4x4 tensor as 4x4 matrix of 4x4 matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, tensors

I'd like to print the LeviCivitaTensor[4] tensor as 4x4 block matrix of 4x4 matrices

The following code works to display the LeviCivitaTensor[3] tensor as a 3x1 vector of 3x3 matrices.

```
Print["\[Epsilon]", 
  MatrixForm /@ Normal[LeviCivitaTensor[3]] // MatrixForm];
```

$\epsilon \text{ = }\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

I'd like to something similar for the LeviCivitaTensor[4]

Comment: why not just `MatrixForm[LeviCivitaTensor[4]]`?

Comment: @kglr  yes that works. I over-thought this one.